# Apply Dark/Light theme locally Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme, android-dark-theme

My app designer uses ONE color scheme for the whole app that some elements are appears to be dark theme and in some other place, light theme.

What I want is to apply the dark theme on screen1 and light theme on screen2. I am looking for something like this:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(Theme provides myLightTheme) {
     Screen1()       
}

CompositionLocalProvider(Theme provides myDarkTheme) {
     Screen2()       
}
```

Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would define dark and light themes separately:

```
private val LightColors = lightColorScheme(...)
private val DarkColors = darkColorScheme(...)
```

Then define a custom theme wrapper that uses `isSystemInDarkTheme()` to auto switch based on system settings:

```
val LocalUseDarkTheme = compositionLocalOf { false }

@Composable
fun MyTheme(useDarkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {

    val colors = if (!useDarkTheme) {
        LightColors
    } else {
        DarkColors
    }

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalUseDarkTheme provides useDarkTheme) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colorScheme = colors,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

So you could then just set `useDarkTheme` as required:

```
MyTheme(useDarkTheme = true) { ... }
```

Comment: and what does it do? `MyTheme` is usually called in top level composable of all screen, calling it in nested composable for a specific screen to set a specific theme doesn't work

Comment: If you want different themes for different screens, you can apply the theme at the screen level. Or you can just provide new values using `CompositionLocalProvider`. Docs have examples of the second approach - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal

Comment: I tried first method, it didn't work, second one allows to set only one color but not the whole color scheme

Comment: Something like...
```CompositionLocalProvider(LocalColorScheme provides newColorScheme) {}```
Should allow you to change any colours

Comment: `LocalColorScheme` is internal in `MaterialTheme`

Comment: So it is... In that case you would have to handle it in your base theme. You could use a custom composition local to change the theme dynamically.